# Understanding signature of data type, typeclass, and making a data type an instance of a typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-kinds

Been reading Learn You A Haskell For a Great Good ! and have big trouble with understanding instance and kind.

Q1: So the type `t` in `Tofu t` acts as a function with the kind signature `(* -> (* -> *)) -> *` ? And the overall kind signature of `tofu` is `* -> *`, isnt it? since `(* -> *) -> *` results in `*` and so does `(* -> (* -> *)) -> *`

Q2: When we want to make `Frank a b` instance of the typeclass `Tofu t`, data type `Frank a b` must also have the same kind with `t`. That means kind of `a` is `*`, `b` is `* -> *`, and `b a` which will be `(* -> *) -> *` which results in `*`. Is that correct?

Q3: The `x` in `tofu x` represents `j a` since both have the kind of `*`. `Frank` with its kind `(* -> (* -> *)) -> *` is applied on `x`. But I'm not sure how presenting `j a` as `x` will distinguish the `x` in `tofu x` which is `j a` and the `x` in `Frank x` which is `a j`.

I'm kind of new to the idea of having a function inside data type or class (Ex: `b` in `Frank a b` or `t` in `Tofu t`) which is a bit confusing

I leave the link here since quoting would make the post look unnecessarily long. [link](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo)

```
class Tofu t where
  tofu :: j a -> t a j

data Frank a b = Frank {frankField :: b a} 

instance Tofu Frank where
  tofu x = Frank x
```

Comment: Is that valid code? Do I need some extensions switched on? All I'm getting is compile rejection messages. In particular, in the `instance Tofu Frank` equation, there's no LHS binding for `t` or `b`. Where are they coming from?

Comment: As well as `:kind` that LYAH shows, there's also `:info`, that tells you everything GHC knows about your names. For example `:i Tofu` tells you inferred kind for `t`; `:i Frank` tells you inferred kinds for `a, b`.

Comment: @AntC im so sorry the `instance` code was wrong. I have fixed it.

Comment: thanks. I found a learnable moment trying to get a result out of applying `tofu`. (Add `deriving Show` to the data decl for `Frank`.) Writing `tofu (Just "hello")` gives nasty type errors.

Answer (score 6):

Q1:

> So the type t in Tofu t acts as a function with the kind signature (* -> (* -> *)) -> * ?

`t`'s kind is `* -> (* -> *) -> *`, or more explicitly `* -> ((* -> *) -> *)`, not `(* -> (* -> *)) -> *`.

> And the overall kind signature of tofu is * -> *, isnt it?

`tofu` doesn't have a kind signature, only type constructors do; its type's kind is `*`. So are its argument's and result's types. And same for any function.

Q2: You start with a wrong supposition: `instance Tofu Frank` makes the `Frank` type constructor an instance of `Tofu`, not `Frank a b`. So it's `Frank` which must have the same kind as `t`, not `Frank a b` (which has kind `*`).

> b a which will be (* -> *) -> *

No, `b a` is an application of `b` of kind `* -> *` to `a` of kind `*`, so the application has kind `*`. Exactly as if `b` was a function of type `x -> y`, and `a` was a value of type `x`, `b a` would have type `y`, not `(x -> y) -> x`: just replace `x` and `y` by `*`.

Q3:

> The x in tofu x represents j a

"Has type", not "represents".

> since both have the kind of *

`x` doesn't have a kind, because it isn't a type.

> Frank with its kind (* -> (* -> *)) -> * is applied on x

No, in

```
tofu x = Frank x
```

it's the `Frank` [*data* constructor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor) which is applied to `x`, not the type constructor. It's a function with signature `b a1 -> Frank a1 b` (renaming `a` so you don't confuse it with `tofu`'s). So `b ~ j` and `a1 ~ a`.

Answer (score 3):

Alexey already had a go at answering your questions.  I'll instead expound on your example with whatever details seem relevant.

```
class Tofu t where
  tofu :: j a -> t a j
          ^^^    ^^^^^
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The highlighted bits *must* have kind `*`.  Anything on either side of a (type level) arrow must have type `*`<sup>[1]</sup>, and the arrow term itself (that is, the whole `j a -> t a j` term) also has kind `*`.  Indeed, any "type"<sup>[2]</sup> that can be inhabited by a value has kind `*`.  If it has any other kind, there can't be any values of it (it is just used as to construct proper types elsewhere).

So, within the signature of `tofu`, the following holds

```
j a :: *
t a j :: *
```

because they are used as "inhabited" types, since they are arguments to `(->)`.

And these are the only things constraining the class.  In particular, `a` can be any kind.  With `PolyKinds`<sup>[3]</sup>

```
a :: k   -- for any kind k
j :: k -> *
t :: k     ->   (k -> *) -> *
     ^          ^^^^^^^^    ^
 kind of a      kind of j   required since is used as inhabited type by ->
```

So we found the required kind of `t`.

We can use a similar reasoning for `Frank`.

```
data Frank a b = Frank {frankField :: b a}
     ^^^^^^^^^                        ^^^
```

Again the highlighted bits have to have kind `*`, because they can have values. Otherwise there are no constraints. Generalizing, we have

```
a :: k
b :: k -> *
Frank a b :: *
```

And thus

```
Frank :: k -> (k -> *) -> *
```

We can see that `Frank`'s kind matches the required kind for `Tofu`.  But it also makes sense for a more specific kind, for example:

```
data KatyPerry a b = KatyPerry a (b Int)
```

Try to deduce her kind, and check that it is more specific than the kind required by `Tofu`.

---

[1] This is even true of arrows at the kind level if we assume `TypeInType`.  Without `TypeInType`, the "kinds of kinds" are called *sorts* and nobody worries about them; there's usually nothing interesting happening at that level.

[2] I put "type" in quotes because technically only things with kind `*` are called types, everything else is called a *type constructor*.  I tried to be precise about this but I couldn't find a non-awkward way to refer to both at once and the paragraph got very messy.  So "type" it is.

[3] Without `PolyKinds`, anything with an unconstrained kind like `k` gets specialized to `*`.  It also means that `Tofu`'s kind could depend on what type you first happen to instantiate it at, or whether you instantiate it at a type in the same module or a different module. It's bad.  `PolyKinds` is good.

Comment: i find your answer very helpful and constructive as always. 2 questions: Is this correct `b a :: (* -> *) -> * -> *`? To your homework is this the right answer?  `a (b Int) :: * -> (Int -> *) -> *  ;a :: k  ;b :: Int -> *  ;KatyPerry :: * -> (Int -> *) -> *`

Comment: sorry i cant get around with line break inside code so it's a bit hard to read. Also one thing. I see you highlight `Frank a b` but not `Frank` on the right hand side of `=`. Why is that so? Does it have something to do with the record syntax?